# MySQL load data infile ("NULL" String in CSV for datetime)

Tags: mysql, sql, import

Hi I am have the following CSV format

```
id   (tab)  creation_date
-------------------------
1           2012-05-04 15:26:45.000
2           NULL
```

For the importing I am using:

```
load data local infile './test.csv' into table TEST fields terminated by '\t'
  lines terminated by '\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
    (id,@creation_date)
  SET
    creation_date = nullif(@creation_date,'NULL');
```

But unfortunately the NULL value (String) is not interpreted and set to a NULL in the column. Instead I get a warning about data truncation and a default date is inserted 0000-00-00....

How can I check: Is String = "NULL" then insert NULL into column?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? Is it datetime?

Comment: yes you are right it is!

Comment: If you are able to modify the CSV before loading to replace `NULL` with `\N`, you can load it correctly without the `SET`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html#load-data-field-line-handling

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-field-line-handling) has rules to how NULL is interpreted in the file depending on you query fields and lines used, in simple terms:

> - If `FIELD` and `LINES` is default values in your query use `\N` (NO QUOTES).
> - If `FIELD ENCLOSED BY` and/or `FIELD ESCAPED BY` is used, use the word `NULL` (NO QUOTES).
> - With fixed-row format (which is used when `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` and `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY` are both empty), NULL is written as an empty string i.e. `""`.

Your use case is the first bullet.

**Read more from the docs in the bottom paragraph `Handling of NULL values varies according to the FIELDS and LINES options in use:` of the section link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "TRAILING NULLCOLS" to insert null values from the file into database.

Ex:

```
load data
infile 'test1.csv'
APPEND
into table tab1
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
id integer <data type> TERMINATED BY ',',
creation_date <data type>
 )
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't follow :( (...and I don't find now docs about TRAILING NULLCOLS). I found out that the value is not only "NULL" but also contains the carriage return cause it s the last row

Answer (score 0):

Beware, it#s so stupid but I managed the error.
Since the date is the last column in the row and no '"' are used to split the columns mysql is of cause interpreting the column with a trailing carriage return!

Solution:

```
load data local infile './test.csv' into table TEST fields terminated by '\t'
  lines terminated by '\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
    (id,@creation_date)
  SET
    creation_date = nullif(@creation_date,'NULL\r');
```

I know it looks soo dirty!

**EDITED:**
so of course using the line termination for this would be wiser ;)

```
load data local infile './test.csv' into table TEST fields terminated by '\t'
  lines terminated by '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
    (id,@creation_date)
  SET
    creation_date = nullif(@creation_date,'NULL');
```

... maybe someone ends up with the same problem and want to follow my path :)

Answer (score 0):

Use \N insted of NULL string and it's work perfectly